# How to retrieve CSS/JS files on Arduino?

Tags: html, css, arduino, arduino-uno

I am trying to create a mobile website and I want to be able to run it on my Arduino UNO for my class project. I am having trouble linking the css and javascript to run on the website. When I run the website it shows just the plain html code on the site. I was just wondering if I am going about this the right way in order to add them to the server.`

```
if (client) {  // got client?
    boolean currentLineIsBlank = true;
    while (client.connected()) {
        if (client.available()) {   // client data available to read
            char c = client.read(); // read 1 byte (character) from client
            // limit the size of the stored received HTTP request
            // buffer first part of HTTP request in HTTP_req array (string)
            // leave last element in array as 0 to null terminate string (REQ_BUF_SZ - 1)
            if (req_index < (REQ_BUF_SZ - 1)) {
                HTTP_req[req_index] = c;          // save HTTP request character
                req_index++;
            }
            // last line of client request is blank and ends with \n
            // respond to client only after last line received
            if (c == '\n' && currentLineIsBlank) {
                // send a standard http response header
                client.println("HTTP/1.1 200 OK");
                // remainder of header follows below, depending on if
                // web page or XML page is requested

                if (StrContains(HTTP_req, "ajax_inputs")) {
                    // send rest of HTTP header
                    client.println("Content-Type: text/xml");
                    client.println("Connection: keep-alive");
                    client.println();
                    SetLEDs();
                    // send XML file containing input states
                    XML_response(client);
                }
                else if (StrContains(HTTP_req, "GET / ")|| StrContains(HTTP_req, "GET /index.html"))
                    {
                      client.println("Content-Type: text/html");
                      client.println("Connection: keep-alive");
                      client.println();
                      webFile = SD.open("index.html"); // open main page
                    }

                else if (StrContains(HTTP_req, "GET /controls.html"))
                    {
                      client.println("Content-Type: text/html");
                      client.println("Connection: keep-alive");
                      client.println();
                      webFile = SD.open("controls.html");
                    }
                else if (StrContains(HTTP_req, "GET /css/font-awesome.min.css"))
                    {
                      client.println("Content-Type: text/css");
                      client.println("Connection: keep-alive");
                      client.println();
                      webFile = SD.open("css/font-awesome.min.css");
                    }
                else if (StrContains(HTTP_req, "GET /css/skel.css"))
                    {
                      client.println("Content-Type: text/css");
                      client.println("Connection: keep-alive");
                      client.println();
                      webFile = SD.open("css/skel.css");
                    }
                else if (StrContains(HTTP_req, "GET /css/style.css"))
                    {
                      client.println("Content-Type: text/css");
                      client.println("Connection: keep-alive");
                      client.println();
                      webFile = SD.open("css/style.css");
                    }
                else if (StrContains(HTTP_req, "GET /css/style-1000px.css"))
                    {
                      client.println("Content-Type: text/css");
                      client.println("Connection: keep-alive");
                      client.println();
                      webFile = SD.open("css/style-1000px.css");
                    }
                else if (StrContains(HTTP_req, "GET /css/style-desktop.css"))
                    {
                      client.println("Content-Type: text/css");
                      client.println("Connection: keep-alive");
                      client.println();
                      webFile = SD.open("css/style-desktop.css");
                    }
                else if (StrContains(HTTP_req, "GET /css/style-mobile.css"))
                    {
                      client.println("Content-Type: text/css");
                      client.println("Connection: keep-alive");
                      client.println();
                      webFile = SD.open("css/style-mobile.css");
                    }
                else if (StrContains(HTTP_req, "GET /js/init.js"))
                    {
                      client.println("Content-Type: text/css");
                      client.println("Connection: keep-alive");
                      client.println();
                      webFile = SD.open("js/init.js");
                    }
                else if (StrContains(HTTP_req, "GET /js/jquery.dropotron.min.js"))
                    {
                      client.println("Content-Type: text/css");
                      client.println("Connection: keep-alive");
                      client.println();
                      webFile = SD.open("js/jquery.dropotron.min.js");
                    }
                else if (StrContains(HTTP_req, "GET /js/jquery.min.js"))
                    {
                      client.println("Content-Type: text/css");
                      client.println("Connection: keep-alive");
                      client.println();
                      webFile = SD.open("js/jquery.min.js");
                    }
                else if (StrContains(HTTP_req, "GET /js/skel.min.js"))
                    {
                      client.println("Content-Type: text/css");
                      client.println("Connection: keep-alive");
                      client.println();
                      webFile = SD.open("js/skel.min.js");
                    }
                else if (StrContains(HTTP_req, "GET /js/skel-layers.min.js"))
                    {
                      client.println("Content-Type: text/css");
                      client.println("Connection: keep-alive");
                      client.println();
                      webFile = SD.open("js/skel-layers.min.js");
                    }


                    //send web page to client
                    if (webFile) {
                        while(webFile.available()) {
                            client.write(webFile.read()); // send web page to client
                        }
                        webFile.close();
                    }



                // display received HTTP request on serial port
                Serial.print(HTTP_req);
                // reset buffer index and all buffer elements to 0
                req_index = 0;
                StrClear(HTTP_req, REQ_BUF_SZ);
                break;
            }
            // every line of text received from the client ends with \r\n
            if (c == '\n') {
                // last character on line of received text
                // starting new line with next character read
                currentLineIsBlank = true;
            } 
            else if (c != '\r') {
                // a text character was received from client
                currentLineIsBlank = false;

            }
        } // end if (client.available())
    } // end while (client.connected())
    delay(1);      // give the web browser time to receive the data
    client.stop(); // close the connection
} // end if (client)`
```

Answer (score 0):

I lack the hardware to test your code, but it seems ok. Except that you are sending JavaScript files with the mime type `text/css` on its header instead of `text/javascript` or `application/javascript` which is also acceptable, but I recommend that you use `text/javascript` instead.

I would also recommend that instead of using `if… else if… else if…` each file, like you did, just get the file name and check whether it exists on the SD card, if not send a 404 response, if it does, send a 200 response. This wikipedia article might help you with the behavior that is expected from web servers: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes

Also, you do realize that `delay(1);` will only wait one millisecond right? Try giving it a little more time, just to be sure.

I hope this helps :)

Answer (score 0):

When you use SD.open, your filename can only be 8 characters max and the extension can only be 3 characters max.

Go through your code and find all of these instances.  For example:

```
                webFile = SD.open("css/font-awesome.min.css");
```

That should fix a lot of your issues.